# Java getting RSS link from HTML source code using JSOUP

Tags: java, rss, jsoup, html-parser

I am trying to get RSS link from html source code. I used [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) java library to find rss link. I wrote a small piece of code to get RSS links, but unfortunately it is not working for all the websites. Below is my code

```
String url = "http://www.smashingmagazine.com/"; // not working
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements links = doc.select("link[type=application/rss+xml]");

if (links.size() > 0) {
    String rss_url = links.get(0).attr("href").toString();
} else {
    // RSS url not found
}
```

The above code is not working for all the websites. Please solve my problem.
(I am trying to find RSS 2.0 links)

Thank You

Comment: Why don't you go the the [smashing magzine's RSS feed](http://rss1.smashingmagazine.com/feed/) and parse it using a java based `RSS parser like Rome`. The above process can be repeated pretty much with any site that provide RSS feeds.

Comment: No the url is not static. User can give any website url, i need to find the rss url and parse it.

Comment: If you observe your webpage it doesn't have `application/rss+xml` instead it has `application/atom+xml`

Comment: Thank you RanRag. But in this url http://dtscinema.com if you see the source code there  `application/rss+xml` is present still i am not getting rss url.

Comment: Are you sure the site is `dtscinema.com` b'coz when I am trying to open it from here it seems the domain has expired.

Comment: Sorry it is http://dtscinema.in

Comment: Its working fine for me. I ran your code for `dtscinema.in` and got this as output `http://www.dtscinema.in/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss`. Are you sure you are printing the value of `rss_url` inside the `if statement` b'coz the code you posted here doesn't print anything if url is found.

Comment: Really. Ok i will check my code again. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is :

```
String url = "http://www.smashingmagazine.com/"; // not working
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Elements links = doc.select("link[type=application/rss+xml]");

if (links.size() > 0) {
    String rss_url = links.get(0).attr("abs:href").toString();
} else {....
    // RSS url not found
}
```

I hope it will be ok for you. 
It works with .attr(**"abs:**href")

Ertu